# Load only initial view and data on application-startup

Tags: sapui5

I wrote a SplitApp with a master and six detail views. Each detail view has it's own data model. The data is loaded in the onInit method of each controller.
I'm just trying to improve the performance of the application. Is there a way to load only the initial detail view and it's data on startup and the other only on request?

Comment: How do you load the detail views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advise! The problem was that i defined all detail views in the XML-View inside the  tag, like this:

```
<SplitApp   mode="ShowHideMode" height="auto" >
<masterPages>
<mvc:XMLView viewName="de.test.view.Master"  />
</masterPages>
<detailPages>
<mvc:XMLView viewName="de.test.view.Detail01"  />
<mvc:XMLView viewName="de.test.view.Detail02"  />
<mvc:XMLView viewName="de.test.view.Detail03"  />
...
</detailPages>
</SplitApp>
```

Now i load each  detail-view  when it is requested for the first time and make use of the *addDetailPage* function of the SplitApp control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add ``async="true"` property to your XMLView?

There are also some articles how you can improve performance of your app:
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/29/sapui5-application-startup-performance-best-practices/
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/19/sapui5-application-startup-performance-advanced-topics/
https://blogs.sap.com/2013/12/21/asynchronous-load-of-sapui5/

Comment: Yes, i configured the process of bootstrapping to run asynchronously. 
But i will also have a look at the other articles you mentioned.